# ios11 toolbar last icon is spaced out

Tags: ios, iphone, ios11, xcode9

I have upgrade my ios app to ios11 and xcode 9. When running the app in the xcode 9 ios 11 simulator i get my toolbar last icon spaced out like this.[image: ios 11 toolbar last icon spaced out]

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I Solved it by adding flexiblespace uibarbuttonitem at the end.

Thanks